# BOOTSTRAP navigation bar's styles are not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a navigation bar inside the class jumbotron using bootstrap. But it seems that there is some problem with the navigation bar menu. There is no padding or styles in the "li" tags. All the li tags just sticked together in the following manner:
HOMEPRICEGALLERYMEDIAFAQsCONTACT US

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>TATTOO</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta class="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<!--create a header first using jumbotron class or header tricks-->
<div class="jumbotron" id="header">
  <img src="#">here comes the image</img>
  <!-- adding the navigtion bar  -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>PRICE</li>
        <li>GALLERY</li>
        <li>MEDIA</li>
        <li>FAQs</li>
        <li>CONTACT US</li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
  </nav>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to add `a tags` to your li tags. this a tag is responsible for the padding--

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>TATTOO</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta class="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<!--create a header first using jumbotron class or header tricks-->
   
   
 <div class="jumbotron" id="header">
      <img src="#">
      
      <!-- adding the navigtion bar  -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PRICE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MEDIA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
          </ul>  
        </div>
      </nav>
      </div>
     </body>
 </body>
```

Comment: Mention not..just accept th answer if it has helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the text inside the list items in anchor tags, you would see it styled :) Let me know if it works

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href='#'>HOME </a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>PRICE </a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>GALLERY </a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>MEDIA </a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>FAQs </a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>CONTACT US </a></li>
        </ul>
```